# Postgres compound index effectiveness with a given column list

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, compound-index

Let's say I have a compound index involving these 3 columns.

```
(name, email, phone)
```

Is this index still will be used for these queries? The first query involves just 2 of indexed fields and the second index using more then all of the fields. By the way, which index type is most suitable for this?

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE emails = 'xxx@email.com' AND phone = '012645678'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = 'dude' AND emails = 'xxx@email.com' AND phone = '012645678' AND title = 'CEO'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a typical b-tree index should be used for the second query (perhaps depending on table statistics).  In general, indexes are used from "left to right", with equality conditions in the `where`.  The first query has no condition on `name`.

No single index is optimal for both queries, but a an index on `(emails, name)` would probably do well.

Note also that phone numbers are usually stored as strings.  Your comparison is to a number.  Type conversions can affect the use of indexes.

Comment: So, if we lave less fields (ex. 1) in query then none of possible indexes which has more fields in it helps?

Comment: @Yonetmen . . . The index is used from left to right.  To use that index, you want a condition on `name`.

Comment: But my understanding from documentation is that effectiveness is the same regardless of which index column(s) the query conditions use for GIN and BRIN index types. Did I interpreted wrong?

Comment: @Yonetmen . . . For these types of queries, you would normally use a b-tree index.   GIN indexes are usually associated with full-text searches, and BRIN indexes are also very specific.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!